# How to place all the divs inside a parent div whose width is 50 side by side, via javascript?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

Class:

```
public class FieldsWrapper {
    public String apiName ;
    public Integer columnNumber;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="case-section">
    <repeat tag here which repeats each value value="{!lstCaseAPIName}" var="eachApiName">
        <div>
            <!--api Name here-->
        </div>
    </repeat>
</div>
```

the lstCaseApiName will contain values from server side : `public List<FieldsWrapper> lstCaseAPIName`, which will have column number and field name.

Expected: If a column number is 1, then it should display in full width : 100%
if column number is 2, then it should display div two divs in single row with each width as 50%.

Is there any attribute in html to do this, or do I need to do this via JS?

For ex: If my loop is 5, then I don't want each div width to be 20%. I want the width to be based on the column number. Say first div has  column number `2`, then only its width should be 50% and it should come at left side, the second column is `2`, the width 50% and should come at right side. if column is `1` then it should cover the full width.

**Update**
Tried using width attribute :

```
 <div style="width: calc(100%/{!eachApiName.columnNumber})">
                             <!--api Name here-->
 </div>
```

It look like this :

[image]

Can I place all the divs whose size is 50 side by side, via javascript?

```
          $('.case-section').children().each(function () {
                let intDivWidth = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;
                if(intDivWidth === 50){
                    // place yhe next div side by side and ignore the div in next iteration
                }
            })
```

Comment: **Divide 100 by your loop length** and add the result value to each rep as an inline style using`width`.

Comment: If my loop is 5, then I dont want the width to be 20%. I want the width to be based on the column number. Say first div has 2 column number, then only its width should be 50% and it should come at left side, the second column is 2, the width 50% and should come at right side.
if column is one then it should cover the full width.